# Follow-up. Is return reference to x++ defined?

Tags: c++, return, defined, post-increment

I recently asked the question [Is the behavior of return x++; defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380803/is-the-behavior-of-return-x-defined)

The result was about what I expected, but got me thinking about a similar situation.

If I were to write

```
class Foo
{   
  ...   
  int x;   
  int& bar() { return x++; }
};
```

Where bar now returns an int reference, is this behavior defined? If the answer to the previous question is literally true and not just a convenient abstraction of what's going on, it would seem you'd return a reference to a stack variable that would be destroyed as soon as the return was executed.

If it is just an abstraction, I'd be interested to know what behavior is actually guaranteed by a post-increment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot do that, as that would be returning a reference to a temporary.

Comment: int x is a member variable, not a temporary

Comment: @John: that's true, but the thing the function is returning (the result of `x++`) *is* a temporary, since it's not the same as the (new) value of `x`.

Comment: from gcc: foo.h:6: In member function "int& Foo::bar()": error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type "int&" from a temporary of type "int".  (It's a temporary)

Comment: But, you can fix it if you add the const declaration to bar - const int& Foo::bar().  gcc will warn you about returning the temporary, but doesn't error.  I don't trust it, though.

Comment: @Greg: Thanks, that's clearer now. I missed the invisible temporary. I was thinking that you would still end up with a reference to x.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will result in `compilation error`. But if you change the post-increment to pre-increment it works. The value of `x` is incremented and then a reference to this modified `x` is returned.

The problem with the current code is that you are trying to modify temporary and this is not allowed for the very reason that they are temporary objects.

From this [Visual C++ blog article about rvalue references](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2009/02/03/rvalue-references-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-2.aspx)

> ... C++ doesn't want you to accidentally modify temporaries....