# Difference between ++ and +=1 in javascript

Tags: javascript, increment

Could somebody explain why the following functions give different results.  The first does not seem to work, but the second does. I'm puzzled because I thought +=1 and ++ did the same thing.

(I'm not intending to actually use this code, it's just to demonstrate the difference).

```
/*function 1*/
function incrementIfZero1(base,element) {

    if (element == 0) {
        return base++;
    }
    else
    {
        return base;
    }
};


/*function 2*/
function incrementIfZero2(base,element) {

    if (element == 0) {
        return base+=1;
    }
    else
    {
        return base;
    }
};

incrementIfZero1(1,0) /* -> 1*/
incrementIfZero2(1,0) /* -> 2*/
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Robin

[Edit:]

Thank you for your replies, it makes sense now.  I had also tried the following statement, which resulted in the same thing as function 1:

```
return (base++)
```

I'm now surprised that this doesn't give the same result as function 2 - I would have expected the brackets to 'force' it to be evaluated before returning.  Any idea why this is not the case?

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses - please see the edit at the bottom for an additional and related question

Answer (score 33, accepted):

when you `return base++` it returns the value of base just before it gets incremented.  You want to do `++base` to make sure the increment happens first then it gets returned

otherwise `++` is the same as `+=1`

[edit] in response to your edit, i tried wrapping random statements in parentheses and most mathematical operators respond as expected, this incrementation seems to be exempt, likely because the syntax of pre-incrementation vs post-incrementation is highly intentional and the statement itself ***returns*** a specific value regardless of whether or not you wrap it in parentheses

Comment: Thanks - I think I understand.  So return (x++) is the same as return x++ because neither involve an assignment to x, so both of them say: "return x and then increment by one".  Whereas return x+=1 says 'assign x+1 to x and return the resultant value of x'.

Comment: @RobinL The *expression* `x++` returns `x` (to the `return` statement, which returns it from the function to the outside) then increments it . The expression `x+=1` increments `x`, then returns it.

Comment: Although it may be obvious, for posterity's sake: **please** do not `return x++` or anything like unto it in production without clear explanation of the timing of the side effect!

Answer (score 7):

> `return (base++)`
>
> I'm now surprised that this doesn't give the same result as function 2 - I would have expected the brackets to 'force' it to be evaluated before returning. Any idea why this is not the case?

The increment operation *is* evaluated, regardless of the brackets. The catch here is that expressions in JavaScript always result in a value, which is then returned. For example, when you do `var x = 2 + 2`, `2 + 2` is evaluated, then "returned" to the `=` operator, which then assigns that value to `x`. The `++` postfix operator (as in `base++`) works differently: it does increment the variable preceding it, but the expression returns the value before incrementation. The prefix increment operator, on the other hand, works as you want, `++base` returns the value after incrementing it.

Comment: I know this is mostly redundant with other answers, but I hope it helps you understand why it behaves the way it does.

Comment: Thanks for this answer - it did add useful additional information on why there's no difference between return x++ and return (x++).

Answer (score 6):

```
return base++;
```

Is post-increment. It increments the value held by base, and then returns the original value before the increment happened.

```
return base += 1;
```

Adds one to base, and then returns base. This is a pre-increment. This can also be written as:

```
return ++base;
```

Comment: Are you sure that "base += 1;" is a pre-increment and not post?

Answer (score 5):

You are returning `base++`. This is the postfix increment, thus, the increment is handled after the return. For this specific case, `return ++base;` would be correct

Comment: @JustinNiessner Actually it isn't. This is true for most (all?) languages that have the postfix notation.

Comment: @Luke - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654715/in-java-how-does-a-post-increment-operator-act-in-a-return-statement (Java) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380803/is-the-behavior-of-return-x-defined (C++) would beg to differ. I actually thought the same thing until I tried to double check for languages I don't use often.

Comment: @JustinNiessner [PHP also works this way](http://codepad.org/Cnlx0yPx). Maybe "most" was not the right word. "Some" would have been more appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

Warning! There's a difference when two different types, a string and a number, are mutated using `++` and `+=`:

When `count` is a string, `count += 1` seems to do type conversion and converts the 2nd number to a string, whereas `count++` takes the string `count` argument, converts to a number, and increments by 1.

```
let count = process.argv[2]

while (count < 5) {
  console.log('Inside of the loop. Count is', count)
  count += 1 // NOT likely what you want! Now, try it with count++
}

console.log('Outside of loop. Count is', count)
```

Another example:

```
> let num = '2'
undefined
> num++
2
> num
3

// VS using +=

> let num2 = '2'
undefined
> num2 += 1
'21'
> num2
'21'
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify a little.

"variable += 1" is the equivalent of "variable = variable + 1". It is NOT the equivalent of variable++!

Something like variable++ can be used in-place, the former is an assignation.

Answer (score 2):

In The first function what happens is:

`return base++;`  // at first base value is returned and then incremented.

In the 2nd Function :

`return base+=1;` //here the incrementation is done first and then the variable is returned.

shorthand assignment has higher priority i.e. it finishes it's job in that line itself

Answer (score 0):

**be carefull :**

x = 1;
y = (x++ * 10 + 1);

**equal to :**

y = 1 * 10 + 1 = 11

**indeed :**

x = 1;
y = (++x * 10 + 1);

**equal to :**

y = 2 * 10 + 1 = 21;

**to finish :**

++x ;

**or**

x++ ;

**there are not difference !**