# How to assign a value to a variable after each interval?

Tags: javascript

I would like to run a script that repeats 100 times.

With each repetition it should be in order

Take the names from an array or list and pass them to my variable. How can I do this ?

I created this as an example and think about how I can install a function there. I've read and tried a few things. But somehow I'm not ready yet

```js
var TestNames = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"]
var n = TestNames[0]
interval = setInterval(function() {
  var Username = n;
  console.log(Username);
  // here is some code                           
}, 2000);
setTimeout(function() {
  clearInterval(interval)
}, 10000);
```

Comment: What is the logic to pick a name in each iteration? Is it random or by order? Does [`var Username = TestNames.shift();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) suffice? What happens when all names are iterated over?

Answer (score 2):

Aassuming the `setTimeout` is calculcated by the amount of names (10000/2000), you can omit it entirely.

```js
const TestNames = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"];

//REM: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval
//REM: Passing a copy of TestNames to not alter the original
const interval = setInterval(function(listOfNames){ 
  if(listOfNames.length){
    //REM: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift
    const Username = listOfNames.shift();
    console.log('Current name:', Username);
    console.log(TestNames.length - listOfNames.length, ' names done.');
    console.log(listOfNames.length % TestNames.length, ' names left.')
  }
  else{
    //REM: Cancel the interval, if listOfNames has no more items
    clearInterval(interval);
    console.log('No names left.')
  }
}, 2000, Array.from(TestNames));
```

> Take the names from an array or list and pass them to my variable. How
> can I do this ?

That depends on your requirements.

- Do you need to keep `TestNames`?
- Do you pick a random name?
- Do you just pick the next name in order?

In my example I pass a copy of `TestNames` to the interval as `listOfNames`. On each iteration I remove the first item from `listOfNames` by using [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) which also returns that removed item and assign it to `Username`. If `listOfNames` has no more items, the interval gets cleared.

Comment: Not my downvote. I prefer this one since it has no timeout and no pesky counter.

Comment: @Gelegen the usernames are not random, I will set them myself. Which are then called up one after the other.  TestNames was a example,can be changed

Comment: Added *count of done* and *count of left*.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const TestNames = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"]

let index = 0

const interval = setInterval(function() {

  const Username = TestNames[index];

  console.log(Username);
  index += 1
}, 2000);


setTimeout(function() {
  clearInterval(interval)
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Please: `index++` and what when it is manages to get to more than 4 before the clear?

Comment: @mplungjan `index++` is very complicated for beginners

Comment: I disagree to teach beginners poor syntax. += is as difficult, Why not index = index + 1 if you want to be really simple?

Comment: Thanks for the many replies, I'll get to work right away and test them all :-)

Comment: But here's another question, would
++, +=, +1

does everything work?

What is bad syntax?

Comment: @Jeffrey https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241877/difference-between-and-1-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a username for each iteration, I suggest this. Also note the use of const and let

```js
const testNames = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"]; // JS arrays starts at 0
const numberOfNames = testNames.length;
let counter = 0;
let interval = setInterval(function() { 
  if (counter >= numberOfNames) return; // don't continue
  let Username = testNames[counter];
  console.log(counter,Username); 
  counter++; // point at the next or perhaps beyond - shorthand for counter = counter + 1 or counter += 1.  ++ increments

  // here is some code                           
}, 2000);
let tId = setTimeout(function() {
  clearInterval(interval)
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Is there any reason for `interval` to be `let` and to assign `setTimeout` to `tId`? Just curious about the choice.

Comment: Using `++` is an antipattern for me. `testNames[counter++]` would make more sense. When you use `++` you imply that you care about the current value, but you want to increment it after.

Comment: @Konrad while that is a stance to take, I entirely disagree. I totally dislike those **assign and use variable in same statement**. It is like using `testNames[index += 1]` in your snippet (if you start at -1). Also it may work in this case, yet it might not work generally if `counter` has more uses.

Comment: @JavaScript I always assign setInterval and setTimeout to separate variables. And I always assign them to a variable to be sure I can clear them if needed.

Comment: I was contemplating the [counter++] but I prefer to set it explicitly. In this case even more important because I wanted show the counter in the console.log BEFORE incrementing to teach SO that the JS Arrays started a 0. Also I ALWAYS use ++ when adding one to anything

Comment: Thanks again to everyone who helped :-)

For my purposes, the code of "Gelegen" works best. Since I can always enlarge my array. So I don't need to know how many names are in it to calculate setTimeout.
I like the counter function of "mplungJan". In the end I would know how many names I have without counting them myself. Now I'll try to see if I, as a beginner, can integrate the counter function in "Gelegen" his code :-)