# Can a function in C++ return something and then execute its code?

Tags: c++, operators

When doing something like this:

```
i2 = i++;
```

The `++` operator will return `i`, and then it will increment `i` by one.

Can a function also return something and then execute its code?

Comment: No. `i++` stores the old value, then executes its code (increment), and then returns the stored value.

Comment: In what practical situation would this be useful?

Comment: If `i` is an `int`, `i++` does not **return** anything. It's not a function. It's an **expression**, and its value is the old value of `i`. Expressions **have** values; functions **return** values. They're not the same thing. When a function returns it's finished; there's nothing more it can do.

Comment: You can look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380803/is-the-behavior-of-return-x-defined) where users discuss the use of `return i++` expression. Some of the answers point out that the compiler generates longer code anyway as if you wrote `int result = i; ++i; return result;`. So it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Show us *what* you want to do as opposed to *how* you want to do it.

Comment: @PeteBecker I like your explanation, please consider posting it as an answer

Comment: When exactly do you expect "its code" to get executed, in relation to the code of wherever this function was called from?

Comment: Would multi threading count?

Answer (score 2):

No, once the scope of a function is over (at the closing `}`), no further code can be executed.

However, the function can store the old state of the input, modify the input, and return the old value of the input. This gives the *effect* of executing code *after* the function returns a value. As an example:

```
int f(int &n) {
  int x = n;    // store input
  n = 42;       // input is modified before return
  return x;     // old input is returned
}

int b = f(a);  // b is equal to a
               // but now a is 42
```

As you have observed, post-increment is an example of where such behavior is useful. Another example would be [`std::exchange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange), which gives the appearance of modifying the input *after* returning a value.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to implement postfix increment by yourself, you would first store the original value, then use increment but still return the original value:

```
Number Number::operator++ (int)
{
  Number ans = *this;
  ++(*this);
  return ans;
}
```

You may check this FAQ for more details: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#increment-pre-post-overloading

So there is no function code execution after return in `C++`.